# Segue not performing swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

[image: View controllers]
This is the code form the 'Opgeslagen Rooster' Viewcontroller

```
class vcSavedTimetable: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var noTimetableSavedLabel: UILabel!

    var timetable: Timetable!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        prepareView()

    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        noTimetableSavedLabel.isHidden = true

    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showSavedTimetable"{
            let viewController = segue.destination as! vcTimetableShow
            viewController.timetable = self.timetable
            viewController.willSave = false
        }
    }


    func prepareView(){
        let savedTimetable = getTimetableFromUserDefaults()
        guard (savedTimetable != nil) else {
            noTimetableSavedLabel.isHidden = false
            return
        }

        self.timetable = savedTimetable!
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showSavedTimetable", sender: nil)
    }

    func getTimetableFromUserDefaults()->Timetable?{
        let timetableID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "savedTimetableID")

        if isConnectedToNetwork(){
            if let id = timetableID{
                let table = Timetable(timetableID: id)

                return table
            }
        }

        let val = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "savedTimetable")
        if let data = val{
            let table = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as! Timetable

            return table
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

This is the code of the destination viewcontroller 'Rooster Bekijken'. The viewdidload() function should be executed, which doesn't happen. I tested it using breakpoints

```
//
//  vcTimetableShowCollectionViewController.swift
//  Ostrea Rooster App
//
//  Created by Giel-Jan Looij on 14-12-16.
//  Copyright © 2016 GJ-Computers. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class vcTimetableShow: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    weak var timetable: Timetable?
    var willSave = false

    //UIVIEWCONTROLLER
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView?.delegate = self
        collectionView?.register( UINib(nibName: "timetableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "lessonEntry")

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.dataDidArrive(_:)), name: .didFetchTimetable, object: nil)
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)

    }


    //METHODES
    func dataDidArrive(_ notification: NSNotification){
        collectionView?.reloadData()

        if let cv = self.collectionView {
            cv.layoutIfNeeded()
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: getDayOfWeek()-1)
            if let attributes =  cv.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElement(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, at: indexPath) {

                let topOfHeader = CGPoint(x: 0, y: attributes.frame.origin.y - cv.contentInset.top)
                cv.setContentOffset(topOfHeader, animated:true)
            }
        }

        if willSave {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(timetable!.timetableID, forKey: "savedTimetableID")
            let encodedTimetable = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.timetable!)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedTimetable, forKey: "savedTimetable")

            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }
    }


    func getDayOfWeek()->Int {
        let myCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        let weekDay = myCalendar.component(.weekday, from: Date())

        if weekDay > 6 || weekDay < 2{
            return 5
        }

        return weekDay-1
    }


    //UICOLLECTIONVIEW DATASOURCE
    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return timetable!.days.count

    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return timetable!.days[section+1]!.hour.count * 2

    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if indexPath.item % 2 == 0{
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "hourIndicator", for: indexPath)
            let dayLabel = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
            let dayIndex = indexPath.section + 1
            let hourIndex = indexPath.item/2 + 1
            let cellHour = timetable!.days[dayIndex]!.hour[hourIndex]!

            dayLabel.text = String(cellHour.hourID)
            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 2


            return cell

        }else{
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "lessonEntry", for: indexPath) as! timetableViewCell
            let dayIndex = indexPath.section + 1
            let hourIndex = indexPath.item/2 + 1
            let cellHour = timetable!.days[dayIndex]!.hour[hourIndex]!

            cell.cellHour = cellHour
            cell.prepareCell()

            return cell
        }
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "dayHeaderCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)

        let dayIndex = indexPath.section + 1
        let dayName = timetable!.days[dayIndex]!.dayName
        let day = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        day.text = dayName

        if timetable!.days[dayIndex]!.dayID == getDayOfWeek(){
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

        }

        return cell
    }


    //UICOLLECTIONVIEW DELEGATE
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        if indexPath.item % 2 == 0{
            let dayIndex = indexPath.section + 1
            let hourIndex = indexPath.item/2 + 1
            let cellHour = timetable!.days[dayIndex]!.hour[hourIndex]!

            var cellHeight: CGFloat = 0

            for _ in cellHour.lessons{
                cellHeight += 23
            }

            if cellHour.notice != ""{
                cellHeight += 23
            }

            return CGSize(width: 50, height: cellHeight)

        }else{
            let dayIndex = indexPath.section + 1
            let hourIndex = indexPath.item/2 + 1
            let cellHour = timetable!.days[dayIndex]!.hour[hourIndex]!

            var cellHeight: CGFloat = 0

            for _ in cellHour.lessons{
                cellHeight += 23
            }

            if cellHour.notice != ""{
                cellHeight += 23
            }

            return CGSize(width: 226.0, height: cellHeight)

        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        let edgeInset: CGFloat = (collectionView.frame.width - (226.0 + 50.0))/2

        return UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left: edgeInset, bottom: 30, right: edgeInset)
    }

}
```

I'm trying to segue from 'Opgeslagen Rooster' to 'Rooster Bekijken', but it doesn't work. It is running in the main thread (thread 1), so that isn't the problem. It gets to prepare(for segue...), does everything. After that the view should change right? But that doesn't happen. The viewdidload method of the 'Rooster Bekijken' ViewController doesn't get called. It hangs after the last line in the pepare(for segue ....) function.

Why doesn't it change to the other viewcontroller? It does work when im accessing the 'Rooster Bekijken' viewcontroller form the other viewcontroller which segue's to it.

Comment: Does Rooser Bekijken have "willSave" variable?

Comment: Yes, it is set to false, by default

Comment: What should I do to fix it?

Comment: I am working on it, as soon as i found a solution i will post

Comment: The problematic segue is "showSavedTimetable"? and you are calling from code?

Comment: this code is from what viewController?

Comment: @sloeberGJ I can reproduce your error, maybe you are implementing the prepareForSegue method on your destination viewController, check if this is the case

Comment: @ReinierMelian, that is not the case. I checked

Comment: can you mark the viewController vcTimetableShow in your image of your storyboard?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130733/discussion-between-sloebergj-and-reinier-melian).